# Why is a message showing in Google Analytics language column?

Tags: google-analytics, language

Today, I watched my website statistics, and I saw there a language called:

> `<URL Redacted>` You are invited! Enter only with this ticket URL. Copy it. Vote for Trump!

I have seen on another forum that I am not the only one that has it.
I don't know if it is bug or kind of joke.

1. What is it?
2. Can it have an impact on my website? (in any way)

Here is a screenshot of my Google Analytics (it is in Slovak language but I think you can get information from this):

[image]

Moderator edit: I have removed the spam URL from this post. It appeared to be `secret.google.com` but the `G` had been replaced by a similar looking unicode character glyph: `ɢ`.

Comment: I don't understand your question. 1) Which Google Analytics report is this showing in? 2) What is the column header over the column this is showing in?

Comment: It is GA referral spam. It is pure junk and nothing for you to worry about. Leave it alone.

Comment: As I suspected... but without the additional info, it was only a suspicion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can ignore this. It has no impact on your site.¹

#### What is happening?

When requesting resources from your site, clients (i.e., bots, humans using a browser, …) can send additional [request headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields) (e.g., `User-Agent`, `Referer`, `Accept`) with values of their choice.

The `Accept-Language` request header tells the server which language(s) are acceptable for the client. Now, instead of sending expected values like `en` or `en;q=0.8, de;q=0.7`, a client could as well send a value like `I like fruits`.

If an applications makes use of these values (and if it doesn’t dismiss invalid ones), it might end up showing these. Which is the case for server logs, or, like in your case, Google Analytics.

#### Why is this happening?

Authors of the request probably want to lure people to their site. Either in the hope that the logs get published somehow (getting backlinks), or in the hope that website owners find these values in their logs/applications and get curious.

See the Wikipedia page about [referer spam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spam). Same idea, different header (`Referer`).

Note about your case: The second-level domain is not `Google.com`, but `ɢoogle.com` (using a "ɢ" instead of a "G").

---

¹ Unless you (or the applications you use) parse/use these values without having security in mind. They could as well contain JavaScript code etc.

Comment: `and if it doesn’t dismiss invalid ones` this is the most important part of this answer. A server must reject any spam requests. Most people only try to create an analytic filter just to hide those requests. This still allows those requests to put load on your server which costs money.

Answer (score 12):

Google Analytics Spam is linking to THIS discussion thread now. If you got to this thread because you saw a referral in your Google Analytics, YOU HAVE BEEN FOOLED. Check the Language for those referrals ("...Vote for Trump"), then read this article for the details and a filtering solution:
http://www.analyticsedge.com/2016/11/heres-a-secret-%C9%A2oogle-com-is-not-google-com/

The updated article now links to this solution:

http://help.analyticsedge.com/spam-filter/definitive-guide-to-removing-google-analytics-spam/

Comment: I'm a big fan of yours, Mike. ;)

Comment: You should remove the cause and not the symptons, see @unor answer above.